# C - Calculating Variance

Tags: c

While trying to calculate the variance using this function I ran into an issue because it printed: -nan(ind)?

```
double calcVar(double* array, int size) {

    double mean = calcMean(array, size);
    double copyArray[50];
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        copyArray[i] = array[i] - mean;
        copyArray[i] = sqrt(copyArray[i]);
        sum = sum + copyArray[i];
    }
    size = size - 1;
    sum = sum / size;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Anyway, `copyArray[i]` might be negative but you are taking its square root.

Comment: The problem is probably in the code that calls `calcVar`, code you didn't show. Please [edit] your question and put that code _there_. We also have no idea what `calcMean` does, or rather we don't know if that function is correct.

Comment: You need to use `abs(array[i] - mean)`. There's also no need for `copyArray`, just use a single variable.

Comment: `copyArray[i] = array[i] - mean` followed by `sqrt(copyArray[i])` seems dangerous. I would expect that this could be `sqrt` of a negative value and result in Not-A-Number (aka nan)

Comment: @Barmar `fabs` I guess or ..?

Comment: @MaxFun The problem with your question is a) We don't know the input to the function. 2) We don't know what `calcMean` is doing. Add that information to the question

Comment: `size = size - 1;
    sum = sum / size;` is also dangerous should `size` be `1`.

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger can help you determine precisely which line of code causes the error, and that will usually help answer the question.

Comment: Also, I seem to remember variance depends on the *square* of the difference from the mean, not the square root.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for `NaN` has already been noted in comments and an answer, i.e. `sqrt` of a negative number.

However, it seems to me that you are using the wrong formula. If you want to calculate variance, you need the **square** - not the **square root**.

So you need to change like this:

```
copyArray[i] = sqrt(copyArray[i]); -----> copyArray[i] = copyArray[i] * copyArray[i];
```

Further it seems wrong to do `size = size - 1;` before the division (**edit** : See comment from Eric Postpischil which indicates that it may make sense to subtract one).

The formula should be:

```
V = 1/n * ( (A1 - mean)^2 + (A2 - mean)^2 + ... + (An - mean)^2 )
```

or in nice math notation:

[image]

(Picture from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

Like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    double diff = array[i] - mean;
    sum += diff * diff;
}
```

Comment: Subtracting one gives the sample variance instead of the population variance and is likely correct for the intended use. Essentially, if you take the average of the squares of the differences from the mean for **all** the elements in a population, that is the variance. But, if you have only a sample of the population, you do not have a complete measure of the mean or the variation. Samples tend not to be “as varied” as the whole population, and multiplying by n/(n-1), where n is the number of samples (the same as dividing by n-1 instead of dividing by n), adjusts for that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's a bit beoynd my math skills. I have added a reference to your comment. Feel free to edit the answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

When `array[i]` is below the mean, `array[i] - mean` is negative, and `sqrt()` returns `nan`. You need to use its absolute value. For `double` values, `fabs()` will do this.

There's no need to put all these temporary values in separate array elements. Just do:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += sqrt(fabs(array[i] - mean));
}
```

Comment: While this avoids the NaN the OP experienced, it does not correct the erroneous math in their code. They should be using the square, not the square root, making `fabs` superfluous.

Comment: Damn it Jim, I'm a programmer, not a statistician. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `double copyArray[50];`.
"i" should be an int or "size" should be size_t.
To calculate variance, you need to square `array[i] - mean` (not square root)

```
double calcVar(double *array, int size) {
    int i;
    double sum = 0.;
    double mean = calcMean(array, size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += pow((array[i] - mean), 2);

    return sum / (double) size;
}
```

Comment: Removing the subtraction of one from `size` is an error. Dividing by `size - 1` is correct for calculating sample variance, as opposed to complete population variance.

Comment: Are you sure the parentheses in `pow((array[i] - mean), 2)` are enough? Maybe you should use `pow((((array[i] - mean))), 2)` to be extra sure the first argument is not mixed with the second. If you do not think more parentheses are better, why is the first set there at all?